# Android FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[lectorc2dmuser@gmail.com]

Tags: android, android-intent, android-c2dm

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.e("C2DM", "Neue Message.");
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, ResultActivity.class);
    resultIntent.putExtra("message", "Message received");
    resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

I can see from my logcat that i get into this method, then when it tried to start the activity, it throws the fatal exception as written in title with the following comment:

android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
(my reply to AndroidRuntime is: "Isn't that what I'm doing?") ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the wrong intent variable to `startActivity()` call. You want to use `resultIntent` to start the new activity and you are adding `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag to `resultIntent` but when starting the new activity you are passing `intent` by mistake i.e

```
resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

change this to

```
resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(resultIntent);
```